# When set a watermark, how to FillRect a row?

Tags: delphi

In DrawItem function, at first call FillRect to brush a row of history data.  But if the list is setted a background image, then FillRect also brush the image.

How to solve this problem?

```
procedure TCnCustBuildForm.lstWizardsDrawItem(Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem; Rect: TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  FillRect(Sender.Canvas.Handle, Rect, GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
end;
```

Comment: Draw the watermark when handling WM_ERASEBKGRND

Comment: And remove the FillRect() in OnDrawItem.

Comment: All you need can be found here http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=16

Comment: This article is about customer-draw, which is different from OwnerDraw.

Comment: If I remove the FillRect(), then after I click several rows, all these rows covered with backgroud shadow.

Comment: OK, if you don't want to use custom draw, then do it with owner draw if you prefer.